# Enough Information? (Linear Algebra over Finite Fields)

Tags: linear-algebra, binomial-coefficients

This problem works over the field $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Suppose $p$ is a prime and the $i\in I$ index the set of $p$ vectors $v_i$. Fix $k$ an integer with $1\leq k<p$.  Let $v_i$ have the following properties:

1. The $v_i$ can be arranged to form an upper triangular matrix with no zero elements on or above the diagonal.
2. The $v_i$ are of length $k$

   Now suppose that: $$\sum_{i=1}^p v_i=0 $$  and there exists $a_i$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ such that: $$\sum_{i=1}^k a_i v_i=0$$ is $a_i$ necessarily zero? I believe that the answer is yes; however, I do not understand how to go about proving this.  Thanks.

Comment: If $v_i \neq 0$, then $\sum_{i=1}^1 a_i v_i = 0 \implies  a_1 = 0$, then $0 = \sum_{i=1}^2 a_i v_i = a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 = 0\cdot v_1 + a_2 v_2 = a_2 v_2 \implies a_2 = 0$ and etc. So I would try to use proof by induction with respect to $k$. But I am not quite sure I understand you well. How does it relate to binomial coefficients? Maybe untag it.

Comment: @quapka: how do you know that $a_1v_1=0$ ? We have $p\ge 2$, and also $k$ need not be $1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I understand the phrase "if $k$ is na integer" as "for all $k, 1\leq k <p$". So, especially for $k=1$ it holds $\sum_{i=1}^1 a_i v_i = a_1 v_1= 0$.

Comment: I think, it means "if there is (exists) an integer $k$ such that the sum is zero". So not for all $k$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde If that would be the case, then it really does not hold, as your examples show. But it somehow seems to me, that it would make sense the way I interpreted, also. Then it clearly _must be zero_ from the bottom (meaning $k=1$) to the _top_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24036/discussion-between-quapka-and-dietrich-burde).

Comment: @quapka I see, so you are right. It follows inductively that all $a_i=0$. The question is rather confusing. Why do we need condition 1.) ?

Comment: I cannot join the chat

Comment: @DietrichBurde Perhaps it is extra information, but it is information that I have regarding the $v_i$.

Comment: @mikwa That is interesting, I see you there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the $a_i$ isn't fixed? Consider $p=3$ and $v_1=2, v_2=1, v_3=0$ as a counterexample.

Then $\sum_{i=1}^pv_i=\sum^3_{i=1}v_i=2+1+0=3\mod 3=0$.

Now let $k=2$, $a_1=2$, and $a_2=2$.

Then $\sum_{i=1}^ka_iv_i=\sum_{i=1}^2a_iv_i=a_1v_1+a_2v_2=(2*2+2*1)\mod 3=6\mod 3=0$.

Comment: Thank you; I need to add the requirement that the vectors $v_i$ be of length $k$, and that when $p=k$, the vectors are linearly independent ($a_i$=0).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counterexample. Let $p=3$, and $v_2:=-v_1\neq 0$, $v_3=(0,0,\ldots ,0)$ of length $k$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^pv_i=v_1+v_2+v_3=0$. Then for $k=2$ we have $1\cdot v_1-1\cdot v_2=0$, but $a_i=\pm 1$, hence nonzero.

Comment: Thank you; I need to add the requirement that the vectors $v_i$ be of length $k$, and that when $p=k$, the vectors are linearly independent ($a_i$=0).

Comment: All right, I have edited.

Comment: @mikwa Then please edit your question, and make sure, you provide all the info you have. Also could you clarify, what the phrase "If $k$ is an integer" means? Whether "If there exists $k$" or "For all $k, 1\leq k <p$. (see the discussion under your question)?

Comment: @quapka I have edited the question.  It means for all $k$ in the specified interval.

Comment: Can we continue the discussion in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24036/discussion-between-quapka-and-dietrich-burde)?